# Can Firebase Messaging topic works well with 100K subscriptions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a newbie to FCM.
I have a plan to create an FCM topic that contains 100.000 subscriptions.
Then I send a notification to the topic.
My question is: will 100.000 notifications be sent out successfully?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: will 100000 notifications be sent out successfully?

Yes, it will. According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging):

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) provides a reliable and battery-efficient connection between your server and devices that allows you to deliver and receive messages and notifications on iOS, Android, and the web at no cost.

So first of is free of charge.

And according to the official documentation regarding [topic messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging), it is said that:

> Topic messaging supports **unlimited** subscriptions for each topic. However, FCM enforces limits in these areas:
>
> - One app instance can be subscribed to no more than 2000 topics.
> - If you are using batch import to subscribe app instances, each request is limited to 1000 app instances.
> - The frequency of new subscriptions is rate-limited per project. If you send too many subscription requests in a short period of time, FCM servers will respond with a 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED ("quota exceeded") response. Retry with exponential backoff.